# What is the most modern way to generate RMI stubs and skeletons?

Tags: java, rmi

The old way of using `rmic` on the command line is no longer seen as good practice so I cant use the command line to generate them for my classes, I've read about generating them dynamically but im not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 3):

> skeletons

Skeletons haven't been required since 1998.

> The old way of using `rmic` on the command line is no longer seen as good practice

Statements about 'good practice' are just tendentious opinion, but it is certainly no longer *necessary.*

> I'm not sure how to go about this.

You don't have to 'go about it' at all, except to observe what is stated in the preamble to the Javadoc for [`UnicastRemoteObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html).

Comment: I have the proxy pattern example in Head first design patterns book (with Java 6). It keeps talking about Skeleton classes. But, only the stub is generated with rmic & skeleton class is not generated. Will the code work without the skeleton ?

Comment: @MasterJoe I've answered that.